# How to get adoptable storage back after factory reset?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, factory-reset, adoptable-storage

Hi I've done a factory reset on phone, accidentally, don't ask how :D
So i had 50% of sd card adopted now after reset there is only 50% with media files adopted partition is gone, how to get it back?

Answer (score 0):

After SD card format it appeared in full size, so I can split it up again. Sorry for hasty question..